# Process Builder - Possible to Pass Record as sObject to Flow?

Tags: lightning, process-builder, visual-workflow

I am using process builder to trigger a flow when an opportunity is created or updated.

Is there a way to pass the entire Opportunity as an sObject to a flow or is the only way to do this is to create variables on the flow side first and then pass/map fields individually within the process builder flow action to get them into a flow.   I know I can pass them as individual fields/variables into the flow, but it is tedious so wondering if a way to pass the whole record that started the process into the flow from process builder.

Answer (score 2):

Starting next month, in Summer '20, you can create your triggers directly in Flow for all record change events, and that's what I'd recommend.